# Compare two matrices row by row and store indices of non-equal rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

What is Matlab-way two compare two matrices row by row and store indices of non-equal rows (without for loops)?

Comment: Why "without for loops"?

Comment: Try reading things like [mcve] [ask] and [help]. i.e., try stuff and come back with an actual attempt

Comment: @AndrasDeak because Matlab has more efficient and elegant ways to perform matrix operations.

Comment: Do you mean a matrix with all pairwise comparisons? Or compare only first row with first, second wiht second etc? What are the sizes os the matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 3 5 7 9 1; 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 3 5 7 9 1];
B = [0 2 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 5 5 7 9 1; 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 3 5 7 9 1];

ind = find(sum(A - B, 2) ~= 0); %returns [1; 3]
```